# if/else if/else menu issue c

Tags: c, if-statement, menu

I'm having an issue with my menu. I get a number from the user but whenever I get a number it just does option one no matter what I do. What am I doing wrong?

```
int main()
{   
int array[SIZE];
int size = readNum();
fillArray(array, size);
char option = 'y';
do
{
    int num = menu();
    if(num == 1)
        fillArray(array, size);
    else if(num == 2)
    {
        int newSize = readNum();
        fillArray(array, newSize);
    }
    else
    {
        sortArray(array);
    }
}while(option == 'y');


return 0;
}//end main


int menu()
{
printf("1)Change the values of the array\n2)Change the size of the array and the values in the array\n3)Find and display the mean and median\nChoice: ");
int menuChoice = scanf("%i", &menuChoice);
return menuChoice;
}
```

Comment: Without seeing `menu()` how are we to know what you did wrong?

Comment: What's the code for `menu()`? That's probably where the problem is.

Comment: Because `menu` only returns `1`? Please show us the `menu` function too, or this will be impossible to answer.

Comment: Also, `option` never changes. You have an infinite loop on your hands.

Comment: sorry forgot to add it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `scanf` function returns the number or successful conversion it made, not the actual converted value. It seems it always succeeding in reading you value, so will return `1` for one successful conversion.

To return the actual user choice, do not assign to it from the call:

```
int menuChoice:

scanf("%i", &menuChoice);

return menuChoice;
```

Comment: ok. how do i change that to return the actual choice that they want

Comment: @kevorski use `int menuChoice; scanf("%i", &menuChoice);` instead of `int menuChoice = scanf("%i", &menuChoice);`

Comment: @kevorski Don't return the value that `scanf` returns.

Comment: just out of curiosity,  int length = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
 would give the entire length of the array that i am using...at least that is what i could find in my research

Comment: @kevorski Yes, but it only works on arrays. As soon as you pass an array to a function, it's actually a pointer and no longer an array so it won't work.

Comment: if i'm using it in the same function it will work though correct? i'm trying to get the size of the array and get the mean of it. so i could  send the array to that function and calculate everything in that one function. would that be legal? @JoachimPileborg

Comment: @kevorski Yes, in `main` you can use that to get the size of `array`.

Answer (score 6):

```
int menuChoice = scanf("%i", &menuChoice);
```

`scanf` returns the number of successful conversions, so if the scan succeeds, you are overwriting the converted value with 1.